# AppStore like progress view with stop button

Tags: ios, uiview, uiprogressbar

I like user interface of Apple's AppStore App downloading. I want to integrate the same in my App but haven't found anything helpful.

---

[image]

---

Has any one has implemented such interface? Is there any third party class available ? I will be glad if I integrate identical interface for video downloading interface in my App.

Comment: This can be put on hold under the official close reason: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Comment: A link-only answer was supplied below, [which is here](https://github.com/PavelKatunin/DownloadButton). It may be deleted in the future, so I'll add it here for posterity. A link in a deleted answer was also supplied, [that was this one](https://github.com/lipka/LLACircularProgressView).